# Overriding non-generic methods by generic method

Tags: java, android, generics, overriding

I want to make automation casting of views in my android project. So, I want to override

```
View findViewById(int id) {...}
```

method by

```
<T extends View> findViewById(int id) {...}
```

method. But java compilation does not allow this, however overridden method does not conflict with parental and always will return object of view or its childs. I found some info, that java does not allow overriding non-generic methods by generic methods, but explanation why is is I can't find.

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ824
This FAQ says that it is impossible, but I can't understand why. As example we have such classes:

```
class Super { 
  public void set( Object arg) { ... } 
  public Object get() { ... } 
} 
class Sub extends Super {  
  public <S extends Number> void set( S arg) { ... } // overloads 
  public <S extends Number> S get() { ... } // overloads 
}
```

FAQ says that they should compile with overloading, but I have strange thing: 
getter returns the same error as my findViewById, but setter compile without errors.

Could someone explain me this thing? Why does java not allow to override non-generic by generic and why setter compiled, getter - no ?

I know, that I can use some another method, for example

```
<T extends View> findView(int id){
  return (T) findViewById(id);
}
```

or

```
<T extends View> findView(int id, Class<T> clazz) {
  return clazz.cast(findViewById(id));
}
```

But I want to understand, why should I use new method instead of overriding ?

```
//1
@Override
public View findViewById(int id) {
    return (View) super.findViewById(id);
}
//2
@Override
public <T extends View> T findViewById(int id) {
    return (T) super.findViewById(id);
}
```

So, during the compilation time, what is the difference between 1 and 2 ? Even method 1 is more general, than 2.

```
//3
@Override
public <T extends View> View findViewById(int id) {
    return (View) super.findViewById(id);
}
```

After I added method as above, I finally realised, that "T extends View" tells compiler, that it is not the same method as without "T extends View". So, in fact, I created new another method, but with the same name and parameters, so it can't compile. Maybe it is not exactly correct, but as I understood - something similar to true.

Thank you all, who try to help me.

Comment: There's no point of declaring a type parameter that you don't use in the signature.

Comment: It is obviosly. I declared it just for understanding. It was after third editing of my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` method in `Sub` compiles because you are declaring a **new** method called `set` that can take any argument `S that extends Number`. .Note you are not overriding the set method from the Super class in Sub class you have overloaded the set method.

With `get` method your are doing exactly the same i.e. overloading get method but this time compiler complains because it is not valid because you changed just the return type of the method. For e.g.

```
public Integer get() {
    return null;
}
```

and you declare another method in the same or child class by changing just the return type of the method like this

```
public Double get() {
    return null;
}
```

then compiler will complain "attempting to use incompatible return type" because in java return type is not the part of the method signature.

You can replicate the same problem for `set` method if you declare

```
public <S extends Number> void set(Object arg) {  }
```

In this case again we just change the return type of the method but to be valid overload method parameters should be different so

```
public <S extends Number> void set(String arg) {  } // overloads
```

will be a valid overload.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I understood, that <T extends View> is something loke a parameter and it is another method, so it is an overloading, not overriding. But it has the same signature, so it does not compile.

Comment: Your welcome, if you find this post useful then you can always upvote

Comment: I require 15 points of reputation :) But I'll do this when I can.